# SQL - CASE statement evaluate INTeger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

In Windows Server SQL, I am trying to change a value if the value from another table is an Integer and not a decimal. If it is a value, then the change within the Case Statement should apply.

I am thinking:

```sql
with numberCTE (valuea, valueaa) as (
  select (number1 / number2) as valuea, valueaa
  from tablea
) 
select
  CASE when value = INT then 'Apple' else 'Banana' end eval 
from
  tableb b
  join numberCTE a on b.valueaa = a.valueaa
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why did you omit `WITH`?

Comment: sample data from the CTE table:
5.000000000000000
4.900000000000000
2.000000000000000
1.212121212121212
1.050000000000000

so since from the sample 5 and 2 are whole numbers, for those matching records, the desired results will be Apple for all the decimal numbers, Banana will be returned.

Comment: @PM 77-1, I forgot.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: You need to [edit] any clarifications e.g. sample data and desired results, into the question.

Comment: And please don't use images for displaying data, use formatted text. And please tell us what datatype your data.

Comment: The posted duplicate tells you how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please explain why the CTE declaration says it will have one column, but the SELECT query inside provides two columns.

Comment: Also, `5.00000000` is **NOT** an integer. It's still a decimal, just one that happens to have all `0`s after the decimal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps using modulus could cut to the chase  `n % 1`

I should note that if `calc` is a float, it would have to be converted into a decimal

```
Declare @Table table (calc decimal(25,15))
Insert Into @Table values
 (5.000000000000000)
,(4.900000000000000)
,(2.000000000000000)
,(1.212121212121212)
,(1.050000000000000)
,(0.950000000000000)
,(0.900000000000000)
,(0.850000000000000)
,(10.00000000000000)


Select *
      ,case when calc % 1  = 0 
            then 'Apple'
            else 'Banana'
       end
 From  @Table
```

**Results**

```
calc                (No column name)
5.000000000000000   Apple
4.900000000000000   Banana
2.000000000000000   Apple
1.212121212121212   Banana
1.050000000000000   Banana
0.950000000000000   Banana
0.900000000000000   Banana
0.850000000000000   Banana
10.850000000000000  Banana
10.000000000000000  Apple
```

Comment: It's only when you use table as decimal... But you can have int in table also nvarchar change decimal  to varchar and try your result. When i change values to decimal in my answear there should works too without problem with modulo 1

Comment: @DaleK  Such anger :)   I just didn't see the modulus approach in the link.

Comment: @SteveC But it starts with text in the first place - and in a rather unfortunate way too, by copying the prologue of [that other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642132/11683) exactly, which may trigger a reaction already. Otherwise, the version of your code that does not perform operations on strings gives wrong result in that it considers `10.00` not an int, and the fixed one operates on strings (`charindex`, `substring`). In all honesty, none of us is even sure that the OP's original column is not in fact a string - I am only assuming that based on the `(number1 / number2) as valuea`.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies in an effort to get the question resolved. I apologize since the details provided weren't really clear and had to be updated a few times. 

I've tried @John Cappelletti suggestion above which has helped me get what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this :
When value is INT =  Apple , else = Banana

```
Declare @table table (IntCol nvarchar(6),DecCol nvarchar(6))
insert into @table
select '10','10.45' union all
select '10.00','10.+0' union all
select '45.23','10,478' union all
select '48.7','78.8.5' union all
select '1','14.0' union all
select '0','10.788' union all
select '100','45.89' 

select IntCol from @table

select 
CASE
    WHEN IntCol -floor(IntCol) =0  THEN 'Apple'
    WHEN IntCol NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'  THEN 'Apple'
    WHEN IntCol  LIKE '%[^0-9]%'  THEN 'Banana'
END AS 'IsIntiger?'
 from @table
```

OUTPUT looks like :

@EDIT i just added  `WHEN IntCol -floor(IntCol) =0  THEN 'Apple'`
and there you go what you expected , hope i helped you :)

[image]

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted it. I am trying out your solution but haven't gotten it to work yet.

Comment: You need just to execute all my code

Comment: He needss to exaplian if 10.00 is decimal for him? OR not

Comment: 10.00 or 10.000000000000 is an Integer

Comment: Just added WHEN IntCol -floor(IntCol) =0  THEN 'Apple' and the result is good now

Comment: @ Adamszsz, I just got to try out your revised suggestion after I tried John's above and noticed that it is now working as well. The previous version didn't work yet. Thank you as well for your replies.

Comment: His version will not work if you have data VARCHAR . If you have decimal column his solution only gonna works. But my solution works for both so it will be real solution , but as you wish